# unable to get use where execute in sql

Tags: python, mysql

the program is just to get the phone number based on the carplate number.

i keep an error of could not process parameter,it must be of type list,tuple or dict.

```
import mysql.connector as mysql

def get_number(carplatenum):

    # Connect to the database
    conn = mysql.connect(
        host = "127.0.0.1",
        user = "root",
        passwd = "",
        database = "py")

    print(conn)
    # Create a cursor
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    sql="SELECT number FROM gov_info WHERE carplate=col1=%s"
    params=(carplatenum)

    # Execute the SQL query
    cursor.execute(sql,params)

    # Fetch and save the result
    result = cursor.fetchone()

    # Close the cursor and connection
    cursor.close()

    # return the number if match is found, otherwise return None
    if result:
        return result[0]
    else:
        return None

# Example usage:
carplate = 'SJJ4649G'
number = get_number(carplate)
if number:
    print(f"The number for carplate {carplate} is {number}")
else:
    print(f"No match found for carplate {carplate}.")
```

if i run it with the normal sql query with such as"SELECT number FROM gov_info WHERE carplate='SJJ4649G'"it would give the correct output.

the changes that fixed it

```
sql = "SELECT number FROM gov_info WHERE carplate=%s"
    params = (carplatenum,)
    cursor.execute(sql,params)
```

Comment: Look at `WHERE carplate=col1=%s` what is col1? looks like typo/artefact to me

Comment: i just tried to change it.it still giving me the same error

Comment: Change `params=(carplatenum)` to `params=(carplatenum, )` to make it tuple. Note the comma.

Comment: changed it to ```sql = "SELECT number FROM gov_info WHERE carplate=%(params)s"
    params = (carplatenum,)```  ```cursor.execute(sql,params)``` it shows a new error of Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement

Comment: Why `...WHERE carplate=%(params)s`? In this case `params` name should be dict, not tuple and it should have key `params`, If it is going to be dict, it's more logical to use key `carplate`